# How to modify System.CreatedBy field in VSTS via API call

Tags: azure-devops

Apologies if this is very naive question. New to VSTS...

We are thinking to use VSTS for our daily project works. Currently, we are on old TFS hosted in-house. We have window application which is data entry tool and when any error generated Staff can raise support request via clicking one button which includes all traceback and any other necessary information for us to debug or they can raise new support work. We are thinking to integrate VSTS for our support work as well by calling API endpoint to create a task in VSTS.

I am thinking to use one service account in code that calls API to create a work item in VSTS however, I need to update System.CreatedBy field to the actual user rather than service account who raises this work item. I have seen numbers of other posts which says its read-only field.

The process is, I create a work item and then update CreatedBy field by calling following endpoint.

`https://XXXXXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/11?bypassRules=true&api-version=1.0`

passing following JSON

`[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/fields/System.CreatedBy",
    "value": "Test, Mr <Test@example.com>"
  },
]`

This doesn't update the field.

Is there any way I can update this field? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#update-a-link

NOTE: System.CreatedBy and System.CreatedDate can only be modified using bypass rules on work item creation, i.e. **the first revision of a work item**.